Cannot access class 'DataClass.DetailStory' Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
I get

Cannot access class 'DataClass.DetailStory' Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

enter image description here
for the code below.
Can anyone explain what's wrong with this?
class ListViewHolder(private val binding: StoryEntryRowBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(data: DetailStory?) {
            binding.apply {
                itemStory = data
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }

